# add to nested json in mongoDB

Tags: shell, mongodb

For an instance I have a json document in mongodb

```
{
a:{b:c}
}
```

Now what am I suppost to do if I want to add to a nested json which will make it look like:

```
{
a:{b:c, d:e}
}
```

I have read the documentation of `update`. It has documented about `$inc`, `$rename`, `$set` & `$unset`. But I want it to add with existing elements of `a`. just like `$addToSet` do with an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/) operator:

```
collection.update({'a.b': 'c' }, {$set: {'a.d': 'e'}} )
```

Comment: for one or two elements its ok! But what will we do when the document will get bigger? :(

Comment: @sadaf2605: You can add multiple criteria fields (e.g. if you also needed to match a value for `a.f`), and likewise for adding additional fields to `$set`. `{ $set: {'a.d': 'e', 'a.f': 'g'}}` is perfectly legal syntax.

Comment: Thank you! :) I was thinking in a complicated way :(